# Cannot list files create by Google Drive Web Application when in Android client in the same project

Tags: google-drive-api

I  have  create   two  client   in  google  api  console.

when  I  create  file  in  android client . It  can  list  in  web application. But  cannot list  in  android  when I  create  by web application.

One  is  for   web aplication,   another  one  is  for   android  application.

Do you  know  why  it  doesn't  work  ?

Comment: What's your scope and are credentials are created under the same project on the API console?

Comment: Yeah, I find  maybe  because of android client's  scope problem. How can I  set  scope ,I trying to solve it

Comment: I added a snippet how to set the scope on Android.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the list of scopes to `GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2` and use the returned credential to initiate a Drive service.

```
credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(context, DriveScopes.DRIVE);
```